# How to set up a local server?

Tags: vlan

I usually develop offline applications but I have this job that needs a local server to serve documents and assets to people connected to the wifi available in the company and I could use some help finding a way to do this. This will be done via a simple static website that is available only locally and for people connected to that specific connection.

I have used Apache before but just for testing some simple static webpages for myself. I tried to use it for this purpose but had a number of problems:

1. IP address of the server changes. In my case I was using a raspberry device and every time I restarted it had a new address, therefore I had to find that address and then enter it on my pc to access the website.
2. IP is really inconvenient for end users. I was wondering if it could have an address like xxxxx.local or something like that.
3. I'm not sure about apache security and whether someone can hack into the server.
   I know this is a broad question but I just want to be pointed in the right direction (technologies needed) and to know whether this is possible or not.

Note: I dont want to share internet connection or serve the website on the web(that i know how to do!). I just want a local website only available over a wireless network.

Comment: Unfortunately "*configuring an application or device to work on the network*" is off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You shouldn't let a server's IP address change. Either configure it statically if it's mission-critical (DNS or DHCP server, domain controller, ....) or by DHCP reservation if it's rather uncritical.
2. Set up proper DNS resolution on the local DNS server.
3. Security is a must. Internal services may not require the extensive protection external services do, but still need to be configured correctly. This a wide field though, you either need to read up on Apache config and local firewalls, or hire a consultant.

I guess these aren't the answers you expected or hoped for, but with unspecific questions you can only get general answers mostly.